# Linking C from C++ in OS X Mavericks

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, osx-mavericks

Having transitioned to OS X Mavericks and XCode 5.0.1, I can no longer gracefully link compiled C files (output from gcc) to a C++ project (output from g++).

The offending pair of commands produced from my makefile are:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` -g -Wall -O3 `pkg-config --cflags flann`   -c -o vec.o vec.c
g++ `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` -g -Wall -O3   -stdlib=libstdc++ -lstdc++  layoutquality.cpp vec.o  `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`  -L/usr/local/Cellar/flann/1.8.4/lib -lflann -o layoutquality
```

To which the linker complains:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>    "load_dmat(char const*)", referenced from:
>        _main in layoutquality-I8HOqy.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Where `load_dmat` is just a function in the file vec.c .  If I replace the `gcc` with `g++` in the first line, then everything compiles and links fine, but clang says:

> clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated

Is there an inoffensive, non-deprecated way of compiling and linking these?  Linking with `g++` together with object files from `gcc` worked fine before I upgraded to OS X Mavericks and the new command line tools.  Any insight into what changed and how to go forward would be great, thanks.

Comment: Do you use `extern "C"` in the declaration of the `load_dmat` that is compiled into a C++ module? If not, a C++ compiler would expect a mangled name.

Comment: No I don't, where should it go?  In the header vec.h or the source vec.c?  Though, I hesitate to edit vec.* because it is used by other C projects.

Comment: In the header, enclose your declaration like: `extern "C" { void load_dmat(char const*); }`. Use `#ifdef __cplusplus` (as in the answer below) to keep C projects untouched.

Comment: You might want to replace "gcc" with "clang" and "g++" with "clang++" anyway, to get in the habit of not using deprecated symlinks to clang.

Comment: Don't think it's name mangling.  See my response to @Inspired

Comment: Both of these answers would affect any project. In this particular case, the build worked, and then it didn't. Neither of those solutions are likely to solve the problem, for if they were the reason for the failure, then you likely would have had this issue long before now.

Answer (score 19):

Adding a "-x c" (without quotes) before "vec.c" should fix it.

If you compile multiple .c/.cpp files in the same line you can use "-x c" or "-x c++" before each list of C or C++ filenames to switch context appropriately.  For example:

```
g++ -x c  alpha.c beta.c  -x c++  gamma.cpp
```

Comment: Thanks for the -x c and -x c++ tip, very helpful.  But I need to supply -std=c++11 to use C++11 with my .cpp files.  I'm getting `error: invalid argument '-std=c++11' not allowed with 'C/ObjC'` now.  Is there a way to do a one-line build with both c++ and c files, specifying the c++11 standard?

Comment: No, I don't know of any way to do a one-line g++ build with a C file and a C++ 11 file, though compiling to intermediate .o files and then linking them should work.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example `Makefile` that let us use `C++` code/function in a `C` program.

```
CC=clang
CXX=clang++
CFLAGS=-Wall -g
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -g -std=c++11 -I.

DEPS=CPP.h
OBJ=main.o CPP.o

RM=rm -f

# compile only, C source
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

# compile only, C++ source
%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)

# link
main: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ)
```

As you can see, we generate our objects separately using `CXXFLAGS` and `CFLAGS` in two separate calls to the compiler.  In the context of Mac using Xcode's clang, clang (`CC`) and clang++ (`CXX`) are actually the same thing.  Only the differing flags matter.  I am just being pedantic by stating the definitions of `CC` and `CXX` in the above example `Makefile`.

Once the object files are generated, we are good to go to link them together.

Note however that you have to do one extra step to make your `C++` code usable by the C program.

In `CPP.h` in this example, you have to explicitly use `extern "C"` to specify linkage for your `C++` code for use by `C`.

For example, like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

double timesTwo(double number);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The preprocessor macros `#ifdef __cplusplus` and `#endif` are to make sure that our header file won't cause C-mode compilation errors and is only in-effect during C++-mode compilation.

This complete example comprises only 4 files.

- Makefile
- main.c
- CPP.h
- CPP.cpp

The `Makefile` source and `CPP.h` are explained above.

For a complete understanding, I am including `main.c` and `CPP.cpp` here as well.

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "CPP.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Running main.c\n");
    double ans = timesTwo(3.0);
    printf("The answer from our C++ timesTwo function, when given 3.0, is %f\n", ans);

    return 0;
}
```

`CPP.cpp`:

```
#include "CPP.h"

double timesTwo(double number)
{
    return 2 * number;
}
```

I trust that this explanation and example clarifies how we can set up our `Makefile`, specify the `#ifdef __cplusplus` preprocessor macro and `extern "C"` linkage declaration to allow C++-to-C interop, and with no erroneous clang warning when we run make.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are a victim of [Name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). To avoid name mangling in C++, use `extern "C"` around declarations, like:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" {
#endif
    void load_dmat(char const*);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: If this solves the problem then I'm curious how the source could have built and linked before.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to name mangling, but unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem.  I added the edit to my vec.h and the linker error persists.