# Treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode

Tags: c, g++

sorry for my question, I get homework in my university, I need make a programm in C programming language, but when I start with on Mac OS (in school we use OpenSolaris I think) I got this problem, can I fix it without Unix installation?

**Console output:** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR2y2.png))

```
MBP-Maxim:cv01 maxim$ g++ main.c 

clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "_main", referenced from:
implicit entry/start for main executable


ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Invoke the C compiler instead of the C++ compiler. `g++` is the C++ compoiler

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Post your errors as text, not as an image.

Comment: @JosephSible I have posted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking C from C++ in OS X Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644816/linking-c-from-c-in-os-x-mavericks)

Comment: @JosephSible yes thank you I solve problem with "treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode", the second problem "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:" still exist...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `g++` is a C++ compiler. Your source file is C, not C++. Use `gcc` to compile C source code.
2. The file you are trying to compile doesn't have a `main` function, which is required to generate an executable. Write one.

Comment: Yes I have no this errors now, and nothing at all... like just new command line after I write gcc main.c 

I have main function "hello world"

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate more on @duskwuff-inactive- reply

For warning like this `clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]`

Your file name is `main.c` instead of `main.cpp` or `main.cc` when compiling with `g++` compiler or use `gcc` compiler for `main.c`.